# Can we call a pytest fixture conditionally?

Tags: python, pytest, fixtures

My use case is to call fixture only if a certain condition is met. But since we need to call the pytest fixture as an argument to a test function it gets called every time I run the test.

I want to do something like this:

```
@pytest.parameterize("a", [1, 2, 3])
def test_method(a):
    if a == 2:
       method_fixture
```

Comment: You can use ```side_effect```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use [`indirect=True`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/example/parametrize.html#indirect-parametrization) for a parameter to have the parameter refer to a fixture.

```
import pytest


@pytest.fixture
def thing(request):
    if request.param == 2:
        return func()
    return None


@pytest.mark.parametrize("thing", [1, 2, 3], indirect=True)
def test_indirect(thing):
    pass  # thing will either be the retval of `func()` or NOne
```

## With dependent "fixtures"

As asked in the edit, if your fixtures are dependent on each other, you'll probably need to use the `pytest_generate_tests` hook instead.

E.g. this will parametrize the test with values that aren't equal.

```
import itertools


def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    if metafunc.function.__name__ == "test_combo":
        a_values = [1, 2, 3, 4]
        b_values = [2, 3, 4, 5]
        all_combos = itertools.product(a_values, b_values)
        combos = [
            pair
            for pair in all_combos
            if pair[0] != pair[1]
        ]
        metafunc.parametrize(["a", "b"], combos)


def test_combo(a, b):
    assert a != b
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, @AKX! What if there are multiple parameters in parametrize? For example,

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("a", [1, 2, 3])
@pytest.mark.parametrize("b", [1, 2, 3])
def test_something(a, b):
       if a != b:
           method_fixture   #Only call fixture when "a" is not equal to "b"
```

Comment: See my edit. Hope it helps...

Comment: It helped! Worked like a charm! Thanks @AKX!!

Answer (score 6):

The answer is accepted and helped for the OP however it is not "conditional fixture calling". It is called always only it behaves differently based on some condition.

So I only want to clarify that real conditionally call (or dynamically run) a fixture is possible using the `request` fixture.

```
@pytest.parameterize("a", [1, 2, 3])
def test_method(request, a):
    if a == 2:
        request.getfixturevalue('method_fixture')
```

See documentation here https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/reference/reference.html#pytest.FixtureRequest.getfixturevalue